# Store password separately from username

Tags: mysql, security, password-protection

I have recently done an overview of my site security following the recent news articles around the high profile websites being hacked eg. LinkedIn

So my question is:

How is it possible to store a user’s password completely separate from their username and other information? This way a hacker could only potentially get a password and not the corresponding username.

Edit: I forgot to say that I'm already storing the passwords as a hash (and salting it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No matter how you do it, there still needs to be a way for the authentication mechanism to tie the username/password together, so what you're seeking to do is futile.

Rather than going that route, you should be storing your passwords as Hash value that can't be decrypted, which is the [accepted best practice](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet).

http://blog.moertel.com/articles/2006/12/15/never-store-passwords-in-a-database

Comment: Spot on.  If you can associate the username and password hash when a user logs on, then so can a hacker when she hacks your server.

Comment: +1, if **you** are acting as the authenticator then you simply cannot separate passwords and usernames. They **must** come together eventually. This is why it is better, in my opinion (and answer below) to **not** implement your own password authentication.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to add a security, is the same as Google Account use. When you login with the right password (encoded in the database using any algorythm you want, however I suggest Bcrpyt) you will receive a secret code on your phone. You can do it using email. It's becoming complicated, you could also add salt and stuff to get the thing harder to hack.

Remember, if you can create it, you can reverse it. Always. It's just a matter of how, time, sometime money and will.

For your question, no. You always need to tie the username (ie: the account) to the password. I guess you could store this in two database on two servers and use multiple server with salt and hash, but the correct and accepted way is simply to encode using an algorythm like I said and compare.

Comment: +1 If you **must** act as your own authenticator then a multi-stage authentication process is preferable.

Comment: +1.  We use Phone Factor as the second stage for logging into our VPN.  I think it's a brilliant solution. I wish such producst were more prevalent.  Two-factor authentication is 1000% better than the username/password model.

Answer (score 1):

Don't store the password, but rather store a *hash* of the password.

Fortunately, mysql provides a secure (one-way) hashing function for this: [`PASSWORD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password)

Your queries simply save the hash instead of the plain text password, like this:

```
update user_table set
password = PASSWORD(?)
where user_id = ?
```

Can check it like this:

```
select * from user
where user_id = ?
and password = PASSWORD(?); // returns the row if password correct
```

The [Password Hashing in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/password-hashing.html) article in the official mysql documentation thoroughly explains it all.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way for you to keep usernames and passwords separate on your site is to simply **not keep passwords at all.**

Delegate passwords and authentication to a third-party service such as Google and implement OpenID. 
http://openid.net/

Then you'll just be storing usernames and you'll have no knowledge of password data, thus it will be impossible for you to originate a breach, passwords and usernames will never have to connect in your system at all.
Here is Jeff Atwood on the topic: 
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/11/your-internet-drivers-license.html

**EDIT:** In response to a comment below, if your google account is compromised then it is likely that all subsidiary accounts are compromised. This is why a secure authentication scheme like Google's is essential. There is no need to re-invent the wheel here. You can further secure your Google account using two-step authentication
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/make-your-email-hacker-proof.html

I see no reason why every site should expect to act as a distinct authenticator... it promotes web fragmentation at the expense of security.

Comment: But if the hacker know the Google Account, he can login anywhere where he has access, same for OpenID. The problem stay the same, you just give the trouble to someone else.

Comment: If a hacker knows your primary email account then he has access to all connected accounts anyway. Even if I don't use openID, I still enroll with my Gmail... so if my Gmail is compromised then so are all my other accounts, as a thief could simply use the "forgot my password" methods.

Comment: I can't believe nobody else voted this up.  Security rule #1 is "if you don't have a legitimate business need, don't store sensitive data".  Considering the prevalence of Password reuse, passwords are about as it gets, and I tend to agree with Jeff's articles.

Comment: Hey, I found a news piece from the U.K. that says Hotail offers 2-factor authentication, too!!!!!  I hope that's available in the U.S.!!!  I now wish I could vote you up about a hundred times just for making me think of checking into that!

Comment: @DavidStratton the real problem is that you're using Hotmail ;-)

Comment: LOL.  I'm one of those nutballs that thinks Google is the new "evil empire".  They have WAY too much data on me.  But saying such a thing is liable to start a holy war, so I'll just re-emphasize that I DID call myself a nutball when I sait it.  ;-)  And I don't think gmail existed yet when I signed up for Hotmail.  It's too much of a hassle to change everything over.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read LinkedIn uses unsalted encrypted hashed passwords using SHA1 encyption.  It seems like it would be wiser to also 'salt' your passwords. If you are salting with random salts for each user then you are in pretty good shape.  if not:

This means generating random bit strings and concatenating them onto your password before you hash it.  In addition you also store the random bit string for each user and pull it from the database when the user provides a password to hash

The password is ‘salted’(concatenated with the salt that is stored for the user) , then that salted string is hashed and verified with the users hashed password in the database
 This almost certainly guarantees unique hashes and makes the hash table of passwords much harder to reverse engineer back into logical passwords because the output of the hash function relies on also knowing the custom salt assigned for each user.

if anyone knows why linkedIn doesnt salt their hashes I would love to hear from you.  From everything I have read SHA1 can easily be deciphered with time.

Comment: From what I can tell, LinkedIn doesn't store their passwords properly because they're incompetent, lazy or both.

Comment: Guessing incompetent, its hard for me to understand that being a matter of laziness because it wouldnt take much time to implement.

Comment: I believe that LinkedIn started off very small and the creator might not have had the required technical knowledge.